# error PropType not found in 'vue' in open source project

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, doccano

i am trying to work on an opensource software for NLP named [doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano),i tried running only the frontend part where i ran the command **npm install** to get all needed dependencies then when i run **npm run dev** it starts compiling and then fails with this error

```
    /home/nissow/Documents/doccano/doccano/frontend/components/project/FormDelete.vue
  33:14  error  PropType not found in 'vue'  import/named
```

and when i checked the **FormDelete.vue** i did not notice any errors and no errors were detected on **vscode** either

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue,{ PropType } from 'vue'
import BaseCard from '@/components/utils/BaseCard.vue'
import { ProjectDTO } from '~/services/application/project/projectData'

export default Vue.extend({
components: {
BaseCard
},

props: {
 selected: {
  type: Array as PropType<ProjectDTO[]>,
  default: () => []
 }
},

computed: {
  nonDeletableProjects(): ProjectDTO[] {
  return this.selected.filter(item => !item.current_users_role.is_project_admin)
},
hasNonDeletableProjects(): boolean {
  return this.nonDeletableProjects.length > 0
 }
}
})
</script>
```

here's package.json content :

[image]

> and here's the second part

[image]

Comment: Don't post images, prefer raw text.

Comment: Maybe you need to install something else, or populate a DB. You don't have anything more in a `README.md` file?

Comment: @kissu there's only instruction on how to install dependencies "yarn install"  and start dev server with "yarn dev" and how to generate static project as well as generating static project

Answer (score 9):

```
import type { PropType } from 'vue'
```

see detail https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/189

Answer (score 1):

It was also a problem elsewhere.
Sounds like a known bug in eslint and typescript. It doesn't seem to cause an error depending on the version.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/composition-api/issues/189

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

i just made it work, by installing yarn and then running, `yarn dev` as it was suggested in the `README.MD` the first time i was doing it with `npm run dev`.